# scipy.interpolate.splrep returning NaN values although everything is OK

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, nan, spline

I'm trying to fit a curve to a set of data containing missing data, using scipy.interpolate splrep and splev.
However, I end up with an array of NaN.
Other people have had this issue but the problem was that they had either duplicate X values, non-increasing X values, or NaN in their data.
So I've checked for both, but still it is returning NaN values...

```
from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev
import numpy as np

T = np.arange(0, 1000, 0.05)
t = T[data != np.nan]
data = data[data != np.nan] #to check for nan values

spl = splrep(t, data)
fit = splev(T, spl)

print(fit)
```

And this outputs the infamous array of nan values...
I've also tried to slice data out with `t = T [::10] etc...`
because one StackOverFlow response have suggested that too narrow x data might end up to this same problem, but I still get an array of nans.

Is there anything I'm doing that is obviously wrong ?

[My data](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07273269181383154129)

[image: My data]

Comment: When I just tried to run your code I got an error on the import of splrev: cannot import name 'splrev' from 'scipy.interpolate'  Whcih version are you using?

Comment: that was a typo, you should go for splev instead

Comment: Done that could you tell me what 'data' looks like?

Comment: its impossible to check without having your data (the graph isnt enough)

Comment: OK sorry, it was just to show what it looked like. I thought it would be bad practice but anyway, I've uploaded a pickle file that you can download by clicking on "My data".

Comment: OK I suspect its due to the nature of the discontinuties. Note that they 'run off to infinity' in opposite directions. You wont find a smooth function that is capable of interpolating that.

Comment: mmmhhh OK... Then I'm thinking about two fix: either fitting a sequence of BSplie between each points, or fitting a sinuosidal function... Do you think it would work out or would it be also mathematically impossible ? (I'll just try anyway...) Thanks for the reply !